# What will happen if we excite a Synchronous Machine with AC?

Tags: motor

Normally we excite Synchronous Machines with DC. But what would happen if we provide AC in place of DC in field winding of Synchronous Machine? Will Synchronous Motor start in with AC excitation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll see smoke I reckon. Think of a transformer with an AC voltage applied to both primary and secondary windings - unless this is totally matching the turns ratio there'll be a lot of smoke.

Imagine a synchronous motor run like an induction motor - you can easily do this by shorting the rotor slip rings. When first powered, the motor generates tons of torque because the induction into the rotor is 50Hz and this generates a field that causes the motor to start to turn. As it turns the "slip frequency" gets less and less until it is a few Hz - it reaches equilibrium somewhere close to (but below) synchronous speed.

If you held the rotor fixed mechanically so it couldn't turn, the rotor induction would be massive and at 50Hz - this is what your question is asking - it would burn.

Comment: I am not sure that it would always smoke and if I am correct it might even just turn .. Be beyond rubbish performance... But

Answer (score 0):

If the AC frequency applied to rotor and stator windings is the same, the motor will consume some energy and turn it into heat. The result depends on the windings' cooling, resistance and applied voltage.

If the frequencies are different, the syncronous motor will turn into a double-feed synchronous machine, and it will be stable rotating at two frequencies: f1-f2 and f1+f2 (where f1 and f2 are stator and rotor AC frequency).

Comment: i agree with your 2nd point but the voltage on the rotor has to be just right or there'll likely be smoke.

Answer (score 0):

A doubly-fed machine requires a poly-phase rotor, while the rotor on a synchronous machine is typically only wound on one axis (they are effectively single-phase). In order to achieve a frequency difference, it is necessary to have a revolving magnetic flux on both the rotor and stator, but the flux can only decrease to 0 and reverse on the rotor unless it is wound in both the q and d axis (meaning that it is poly-phase). In short, a normal synchronous machine can't be used as a doubly-fed induction machine.

To answer the original question, it is entirely possible to apply AC on both the rotor and the stator of a synchronous machine, as long as the current flowing in the coils doesn't exceed the coil rating, but there is no benefit to doing so. Providing an AC current to the field would cause it to reverse poles at the exciting frequency, potentially causing instability during ordinary operation, but providing no benefit or aid for starting.

That said, it would be very difficult to apply 50 or 60Hz AC to the rotor on a synchronous machine. The inductance of the rotor on such a machine is typically on the order of 1 H or greater (depending on the size of the motor), so the impedance to drive at 50Hz would be about 300 Ohms while the impedance at 60Hz would be about 377 Ohms. This means that driving at 377 VAC at 60Hz would result in about 1A of AC current on the rotor. Rotor currents for a synchronous machine with a 1H rotor inductance would tend to run closer to 10ADC, so the impressed AC would make very little difference.

Answer (score 0):

About 2009, TECO informed me they could use VFD start on synchronous motor, but had to change excitation to ac.  The project didn't get funded so it never went any further.

Comment: This is not really a good answer for this Q&A format. Please don't use answers as a way to write comments on a question.